# create button can click only one time in 24 hours

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

i'm trying to create button can click only one time in 24 hours , Even if user left the page and came back, he finds it unavailable until the 24h end , I don't mind any possible way (java script , database , jquery , php).
thank you all guys

i have this code html:

```
  <form action="#" method="POST">

<div class="card1" id="card1">
            <h3>book 1</h3>
         <button id="roll1""name="roll1"><a href="bbb.php">read now</a></button>
    </div>
<div class="card2" id="card2">
        <h3>book 2</h3>            
         <button id="roll2" "name="roll2"> <a href="ccc.php">read now</a></button>
    </div>
<div class="card3" id="card3">
        <h3 >book 3</h3>
         <botton id="roll3" "name="roll3""> <a href="aaa.php">read now</a></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to do that but when user refresh the button back Enabled :

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['roll'])) {

echo 'you can not click , try again later'; 
}

?>

<form action="aaa.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="roll" <?php echo isset($_POST["roll"]) ? 
     "disabled" : "";?>>read now </button> 
</form>
```

Comment: What have you researched / tried, then? Where are you stuck, exactly? I don't see a question or problem statement here. Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: One approach is that you can store the number of clicks in a databse and increment it every time a user clicks the button legitimately. Each time they click you must check if the click falls less than 1 day after the last click. If so, tell them they have to wait.

Comment: If you have PHP, you can just do some session and disable it based on the time. Otherwise, you can just use local storage. Do realize though that the user can easily bypass this though.

Comment: Your version doesn't keep track of the clicks, as you say it can be reset by just reloading the page. You need a solution with some more permanent storage of the click history for each user/session, as we've described

Comment: How good does the solution have to be? This is an impossible problem against a determined, skilled attacker. If there's a level of "good enough" that's acceptable, you should explain. Cookies can be cleared, second email addresses can be made, multiple credit cards can be used if you tried a $1 charge for validation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with session. If session is persisted to a DB, It will be better, because the user can delete the session on the browser.

On your ***index.php*** file (where your form is), you can have this :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form action="aaa.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="roll" value="roll"
        <?php
        echo isset($_SESSION["lock_timestamp_24h"]) &&
         date('m/d/Y H:i:s', time())  <= date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $_SESSION["lock_timestamp_24h"]) ? 'disabled' : ''
        ?>
    >read now
    </button>
</form>
```

As I see in your question you post on ***aaa.php*** file. So on this file, you could do this :

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['roll'])) {
    if( !isset($_SESSION["lock_timestamp_24h"]) ) {
        $_SESSION["lock_timestamp_24h"] = strtotime("+ 1 day", (new DateTime())->getTimestamp());
    }
}
```